# Compare two NSDate with .nanosecond granularity

Tags: uikit, nsdate

I've tried to compare two NSDate using .nanosecond granularity:

```
let d1 = date1.absoluteDate // 501178812.31100011 (2016-11-18T16:20:12.311Z)
let d2 = date2.absoluteDate // 501178812.21199989 (2016-11-18T16:20:12.212Z)
let result = Calendar.current.compare(d1, to: d2, toGranularity: .nanosecond) // .orderedSame???
```

However while nanoseconds are different (d1=31100011 and d2=21199989) the comparison results is .orderedSame.
Is this a bug of NSDate or a precision-related issue?

I'm not sure it's a bug because on [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtDates.html) I've found:

> "[NSDate]...makes possible a wide and fine-grained range of date and time
>   values, giving precision within milliseconds for dates 10,000 years
>   apart..."

But...why then compare method allows nanosecond as granularity?

Comment: It seems like a bug!